# Javascript arrays pass by value not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects as

```
var obj = {'name': 'John'};
var obj2 = {'name': 'Sam'};
var arr = [];
arr.push(obj);
arr.push(obj2);
```

Now I create a new array `arr2` as

```
arr2 = arr.slice();
```

Now if I change `arr2[0]['name'] = 'David';`

then `arr1[0]['name']` also becomes `'David';`

How can we prevent any object value of `arr` from changing when `arr2` object values are changed.

Comment: You're cloning the array, but not the objects; they're still references.

Comment: Is there a way we can prevent the objects from changing? What would be a better approach

Comment: You are looking for **deep** cloning/copying: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+array+deep+copy , https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20deep%20copy

Answer (score 1):

You’ll have to clone each object, not just the array:

```
function cloneObject(obj) {
    var result = {};

    for (var k in obj) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, k)) {
            result[k] = obj[k];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

var arr2 = arr.map(cloneObject);
```

---

> Is there a way we can prevent the objects from changing?

Yes, there’s [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze):

```
arr.forEach(Object.freeze);
```

Comment: Why not just `if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k))`?

Comment: @elclanrs: It’s just for the case of using user input as keys of a dictionary; they can type `hasOwnProperty` and break things. It’s not usually something one has to worry about, but utility functions should be robust, after all =)

Answer (score 0):

When you copy the array you are only copying the values in the array, but the values are references to objects. You end up with two separate arrays, but with references to the same objects.

You would need to make a deep copy, i.e. copy everything at every level:

```
var arr2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Now you have a completely separate copy of the array and everything in it.